# how to record an ir signal from an AC remote using LIRC in raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, lirc

i had already used the LIRC of the raspberry pi to record and use the IR signals of a samsung TV remote. the recording process was fine. i used [this](http://alexba.in/blog/2013/01/06/setting-up-lirc-on-the-raspberrypi/) site for reference.But now i am unable to record the IR signals from a bluestar AC in the same method. After 1-3 dots (not always the same number), irrecord exits with the following error message:

```
irrecord: could not find gap.  
irrecord: gap not found, can't continue
```

then i tried recording the AC remote signals using mode2 and routing it to a text file and manually modified the lircd.conf file to include the raw code as shown in the link

[How to use irrecord with 2ms timing instead of the default 5ms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652156/how-to-use-irrecord-with-2ms-timing-instead-of-the-default-5ms)

but then i get the error that

```
irsend: command failed: SEND_ONCE /etc/lirc/lircd.conf KEY_POWER   
irsend: unknown remote : "/etc/lirc/lircd.conf"
```

Comment: I created an extensive [tutorial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70945/setting-up-a-remote-control-using-lirc) on stackexchange on how I managed to remote control my TV using only a Raspberry Pi and an old Infrared diode from an old remote control.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly lircd doesn't accept all characters (e.g. slash) for the remote name. Try changing the:

```
    name /etc/lirc/lircd.conf
```

in the .conf file to a different name (e.g. MY_REMOTE), then invoke the irsend like:

```
irsend SEND_ONCE MY_REMOTE KEY_POWER
```

Answer (score 0):

The air conditioning controls send more bits than the television ones for example. You have to configure the lirc.conf header as:

```
begin remote

  name  IRAIR1
  bits           48     #Configuración para 48 bits 
  flags SPACE_ENC       
  eps            30
  aeps          100
  header         3388 1678
  one             430 1257
  zero            430  412
  ptrail          428
  gap          108399

      begin raw_codes 
          name KEY_POWER
     3478     1676      500     1218      501      388
      472    ..................................

      end raw_codes

end remote
```

I think exactly what 48 bits are sending. This guy explains it: http://absurdlycertain.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/lirc-raspi-remote-control-configuration.html

Do not forget to restart the device, with me it does not work if I do not.

Sorry for my English

Comment: By the way to send I do it like this: irsend SEND_ONCE IRAIR1 KEY_POWER